# Surface triangulation from constant depth planar contours

Tags: tessellation

I am trying to develop an application that converts a parallel set of input contours(polygons) with constant Z values to a tessellated surface mesh .The contours may also consist of holes

All available tessellation techniques like glu,delaunay talk about 2d triangulations only.
Can anyone suggest a way forward?

Best Regards,
Praveen